# Не могу авторизоваться через VkNet

Tags: c#, .net, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пытаюсь авторизоваться в **VK** через **VkNet**. Мой код:

```
VkApi api = new VkApi();
ApiAuthParams parameters = new ApiAuthParams()
{
    ApplicationId = 666,
    Login = "XXXXXXXXXXX",
    Password = "XXXXXXXX",
    Settings = Settings.All
};

api.Authorize(parameters);

Console.WriteLine($"Token info: {api.Token}");
```

Выбрасывает исключение при вызове `api.Authorize()`:

> Необработанное исключение: VkNet.Exception.VkApiException: Form element not found.

Двухфакторная авторизация стоит, живу не в Украине, пароль и логин вводил правильно. Пытался ставить более ранние версии библиотеки - не помогло.

Answer (score 3):

Нашел решение. Как оказалось, это происходит, если указать `Settings.All` или `Settings.Messages`.

Comment: а как тогда получить разрешение на отправку сообщений?