# Ошибка VKNET в Xamarin Forms Form element not found

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, vknet

Пытаюсь написать тестовое приложение на Android с помощью Visual Studio 2022 Enterprize Xamarin.Forms.

Использую библиотеку VKNET для подключения к соц-сети ВКонтакте.
при попытке сделать авторизацию через :

```
vk.Authorize(new VkNet.Model.ApiAuthParams { 
ApplicationId = 51711911, 
Login = "***********", 
Password = "*************", 
Settings = Settings.All });
```

> Вылетает ошибка: VkNet.Exception.VkApiException: Form element not found.

Так же ради интереса так как нигде не нашёл фикса или как самому пофиксить, попробовал этот же код для WIN FORM Майкрософт, на win form всё заработало отлично с 1 раза.
Искал информацию по Xamarin.Forms к сожалению так же не нашёл, подскажите пожалуйста как с этим бороться?
Так же прикрепляю фото ошибки с мобилки.
[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TMMs.jpg)

введите сюда описание изображения

[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62mnL.jpg)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/865147/220553 Наверно, что-то вроде [этого](https://github.com/vknet/vk/issues/886) у вас. Ну а вообще, на сколько я понял, из ошибки можно выдрать конкретный ответ от сервера, в котором сказано что конкретно ему не нравиться, так что, изучайте ошибку, а не просто ссылайтесь на скриншоты.

Comment: Да я пробовал менять Settings без разницы, какой ты не ставь итог один, ошибка не меняется если его вообще убрать.

Answer (score 0):

Как и написал выше EvgeniyZ что есть решение, да есть, необходимо установить дополнение к VKNET библиотеке: AudioByPass. Что позволяет обойти ограничения на Сообщения,аудио и друзей.
После этого получилось войти в аккаунт ВКонтакте:
КОД:

```
try
            {
                var services = new ServiceCollection();
                services.AddAudioBypass();
                vk = new VkApi(services);
                vk.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams
                {
                    Login = loginText.Text,
                    Password = passwordText.Text
                });
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Ошибка!", ex.Message.ToString(), "ОК");
            }
            
            if(vk.IsAuthorized)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Успешная авторизация!", "Вы успешно авторизовались!", "OK");
            }
```